# Etiquette of amending others' published work

Tags: ethics, etiquette

I would like to use a psychology framework that has been published by a third party but amend one aspect of it. I intend, of course, to reference and attribute the model and make it clear that the amendment is mine. Would that approach be in line with etiquette?

Answer (score 6):

Etiquette is neither here nor there in this matter, as pretty much all of academia is based on taking what has gone before, and augmenting / amending / modifying / building on it.

What matters is whether what you are doing is **rigorous**. Referencing, attribution, and identifying your own contribution, makes the *writing* rigorous. As to the crucial question of whether or not your amendment to the framework is *scientifically* rigorous, is only something that someone close to the subject can know.